# assistance in sorting an array of pointers pointing to a string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, pointers

I have been attempting to find a way to sort an array of pointers (pointing to strings) and then display the non-sorted list and the sorted list but no mater what I try the 2nd printed list is always identical to the original non-sorted list.  Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated (and I'm sorry if my code is a mess I'm a new student)

this is my main(lab5.cpp)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    student stu;
    stu.list();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my header(student.h)

```
#include <string>
class student
{
public:
    student( );
    void setnameage();
    int getage(int);
    std::string getname(int);
    void sort();
    void list();

 private:
     std::string name[50];
     std::string nameL[50];
     int age[50];
     std::string * Pname ; 
     int * Page; 
     int amount;   
 };
```

This is my object (student.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "student.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//constructor
student::student()
{
    int i = 0;
    amount = 0;
    Pname = name;
    Page = age;
    while (i != 50)
    {
        age[i] = 0;
        name[i] = "A";
        i = i +1 ;
    }
    std::cout << "Enter number of students(max 50) \n" << ">";
    std::cin >> amount;
}

//sets the neame and the age
void student::setnameage()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i != amount)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter name " << i+1 <<" (last, first):";
        std::cin >> name[i] >> nameL[i];
        std::cout << "enter age";
        std::cin >> age[i];
        i++;
    }
}

//get age
int student::getage(int i)
{
    return age[i];
}

//get name   
std::string student::getname(int i)
{
    return name[i];
}

//sorts the aray of pointers
void student::sort()
{
    std::string tempL;
    int tempN;
    i = 0
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j <= amount; j++)
        {
            if(Pname[i].compare(Pname[j]) > 0)
            {
                tempN = Page[i];
                Page[i] = Page[j];
                Page[j] = tempN;
                // tempL = Pname[i];
                Pname[i].swap(Pname[j]);
                //Pname[j] = tempL;
            }
        }
    }
}

//displayes the final results         
void student::list()
{
    setnameage();
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "original list\n-------------";
    while(i != amount)
    {
        std::cout<< "\n" << getname(i) << ">" << getage(i);
        i++;
    }
    sort();
    i = 0;
    std::cout << "\nAlphabetized list\n-------------";
    while(i != amount)
    {
        std::cout<< "\n" << Pname[i] << ">" << Page[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct the tabulation and general format. It will make reading your code much easier and maybe you will get more help.

Comment: You're trying to sort by `Pname`, and yet you never assign `Pname` a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say your program has a lot of design problems, but to answer your actual question:

The trouble is you don't have an array of 50 pointers, you just have one pointer to the start of the array. In your sort function you have this line to swap the string pointers:

```
Pname[i].swap(Pname[j]);
```

But this doesn't swap the pointers, it swaps the original strings. So instead of ending up with the original array of strings, and a re-ordered array pointing to those strings, you just end up with an array of re-ordered strings.

You should change `std::string* pName;` to `std::string* pName[50];`. At the start of your program, initialise the array to point to the strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) pName[i] = &name[i];
```

Then in your sort function you should use `std::swap()` to swap the pointers themselves:

```
std::swap(pName[i], pName[j]);
```

Finally, since `pName[i]` is now a pointer, whenever you actually want to access the string you have to dereference the pointer. For example,

```
if(Pname[i].compare(Pname[j]) > 0)
```

becomes

```
if(Pname[i]->compare(*Pname[j]) > 0)
```

The same problem exists with your method of sorting the ages.

A much better design for your program would be to use `std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>` to store the names and ages. Then you can use the built in sorting functions to sort the list (and easily make a copy of it if you need to keep the original as well).

Comment: How is `std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>` better than `vector` of the same thing (or at least `std::array if the size is constant)? Or even `std::map`?

Comment: @DanM. No idea, if you'd asked me 5 years ago I might have known why I said that...

Comment: yeah. Only noticed the date after I've commented. SO probably recommended me this question since there are still no accepted answers =) Oh well...